# Web Service state with HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable

Good afternoon. Designing a web service that uses a login (and other actions) and keeps all user data and passwords in memory (does not use any database) I have been doubts when to ensure a decent standard of efficiency:

First, choose what data structure to store the information. While I think a `HashMap` would be a good choice, where would be the keys usernames and other information (or just the password) values would be, I wonder if there are other data structures that fit better.

In addition, in the case of `HashMap`, would it be better to use `separateChainnig` or `LinearProbing` as a strategy for conflict resolution? In the case of `separateChaining` we face one of the lists of the "gaps" of Hashmap out very long and complex ascended to linear order in the worst case, but `LinearProbing` could be many rehashes.

What is your opinion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `What is your opinion?` my opinion this questions should be closed as opinion-based

Comment: Using the session map which is available in J2EE compliant web servers is the first thing which comes to my mind.  Besides this, would you be allowed to use an in-memory database such as H2?

Comment: Just an idea, why not use [Trie tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure insted

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some in-memory persistence storage like Redis, H2..... and many more are available which are open source instead of relying on non persistable storage. These have their own data-structure support like map, list etc.

But if you still want to use a hashmap that's a pretty good choice if you have a unique key across. But answering your next question(separateChainnig or LinearProbing). Why do you really care about implementing an hashmap when java already provides you a better hashmap performance in Java 8. Check out an example here http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/04/hashmap-performance-improvements-in.html